# Component had no action handler for... Behaviour changes between ember 2.8.0 and 2.8.1

Tags: ember.js

Please see this [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/00c110c26ca37a29019124f7ad46001d).

What I want is to provide custom buttons with custom actions to a component. The component itself does not know about the actions involved, these actions are expected to bubble to the corresponding controller.

This code works in ember 2.8.0 but not in the current release version (2.8.2). Please use the twiddle to change between emberjs "2.8.0" and "release". Is this an emberjs bug?

Comment: Could you post more code and expected outcome, this does not look like something you want to do in ember. Could use block components etc. I mean you're injecting stuff into component, obviously its content is component.js not controller

Comment: My real use case is a table-component. This is the way how I inject actions (buttons) into a table cell. The table component is used in different places and cannot have all actions that are defined for different content types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's Bug in ember version 2.8.0 alone. this has been fixed in next version 2.8.1.
Related link : https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/14291/files

For your use case, I created [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/f842b1bf71c0333aa3b31b5facae3d78?openFiles=templates.components.my-button.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-button.hbs)

Have actions in application controller,

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
  actions:{
    buttonMethod(){
      console.log('buttonMethod');
    }
  }
});
```

Create my-button component so that it can be included in any of the component. this will call closure action which is passed from parent component.

In `my-button.hbs`

```
<button {{action buttonMethod }}> ButtonComponent </button>
{{yield}}
```

create `my-component` component and send closue action buttonMethod to `my-button` component.
In `my-component.hbs`

```
{{my-button buttonMethod=buttonMethod }}
{{yield}}
```

In `application.hbs`, this is place we are creating closure action to `buttonMethod` action in controller. so we need to pass this `buttonMethod` property all the way down to button component.

```
{{my-component buttonMethod=(action 'buttonMethod') }}
```

Comment: Actually, the 2.8.0 behaviour is what I would like to have. How can this be solved in 2.8.1 and later? I'm trying to use closure actions, currently without success... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks as if you abused a bug :D

Comment: Thank you @kumkanillam for providing the link. The tests provide the (hopefully) correct way to simply add "target=this" to the action. That seems to do what I want...

Comment: Sorry, that was to early. I was mistakenly checking with 2.8.0. I still have no clue how to get this to work in 2.8.2.

Comment: Nice and correct solution. you need to figure out the conditionals to show the button if needed..In addition, the my-button component.js could simply have "tagName" of button

Comment: Thank you all. I wish the "bug" would never have been detected... ;-) This means a major reconstruction of my nested components...